# output value of function doesnt match with printf values in cycle

Tags: c, arrays

I have to create a function to write out available letters from the alphabet. For example, the user types `a` and the function output will be `bcdefgh...`

If I use `printf` in cycle everything is okay. However, if I write that letter into array and then I want to print out array I get the full alphabet on output.

```
void getAvailableLetters(const char lettersGuessed[],char availableLetters[]){
char abeceda[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','q','p','r','s','t','v','u','w','x','y','z'};
printf("Available letters: ");
int x=0;
int i;
for( i=0 ; i<strlen(abeceda); i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<strlen(lettersGuessed); j++){
        if(abeceda[i] == lettersGuessed[j]){
            x=1;
        }
    }
    if(x==0){
        availableLetters[i]=abeceda[i];
        //printf("%c",abeceda[i]);
    }
    x=0;
}
printf("%s",availableLetters);}
```

If I use that `printf` in the comment the output is good, but the output from array `availableLetters` contains the full alphabet.

Comment: `,'z'};` --> `,'z', 0};`

Comment: Translating BLUPIXY's comment -- if you are going to use the `abededa` character array as a `string`, you must `null-terminate` the array like a `string`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

availableLetters[i]=abeceda[i];

this is wrong obviously as availableletters contains less letters then the entire alphabet, so i can not be used for the index. You also never set a null byte into the completed availableletters char array, so it should not be printable as a string at all. You should probably clean available letters out ie
availableLetters[0] = 0;
then give it its own incrementer say 
int j = 0;
then up j when adding a letter to the array
and at the end make availableLetters[ j+1] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Well its clear, there is no place where you remove the letter from alphabet string, you need something like

```
        if(abeceda[i] == lettersGuessed[j]){
              for(int k=i;k<strlen(abeceda);k++){
                  abeceda[k]=abeceda[k+1];
              }
              x++;
        }
```

this should remove the letter from string, also moves terminator to a new index